# jQuery check if one checkbox is checked and another unchecked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I got this HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkw" "checked" />Woman<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkm" />Männer<br>
```

I want to find out if `checkw` is checked and `checkm` is **unchecked** so I tried different ways like:

```
if($('#checkw').prop('checked') || $('#checkm').prop('unchecked'))
    {
        alert("w");
    }
```

and

```
if($('#checkw').is(':checked') || $('#checkm').is(':unchecked'))
    {
        alert("w");
    }
```

and

```
if($('#checkw').is(':checked',true) || $('#checkm').is(':checked',false))
    {
        alert("w");
    }
```

But I always get the alert when `checkm` is also checked.
Any ideas?

Comment: Use `&&` instead `||`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use and(`&&`) operator instead of or(`||`) operator to satisfy both condition.

also there is no `:unchecked` selector, use `!$('#checkm').is(':checked')` i.e. nor operator with is checked condition:

```
if($('#checkw').is(':checked') && !$('#checkm').is(':checked'))
{
    alert("w");
}
```

Comment: Thanks :D I will check asap because you were some seconds faster

Answer (score 1):

Use `&&` which means both should be `true` and `!` operator.

```
if($('#checkw').prop('checked') && !$('#checkm').prop('checked')) {
   alert("w");
}
```

Comment: It's for search, men women or both ^^

Comment: @Matt123456 ah! Okay. I thought you were asking for the gender.